# Automating Jenkins Job with extended choice parameter

Tags: python, bash, jenkins, curl

I'm trying to run a jenkins job from bash using cURL.

My job includes some string inputs, file inputs and one extended choice parameter input.

Passing normal string parameters or file parameters works for me fine, but I just don't succeed in adding multiple values for the extended choice parameter input (Extended Choice Parameter - A common plugin in Jenkins allowing to add a list of checkboxes).

This is what I'm trying now for all of the fields:

```
curl -X POST [JENKINS_URL]/job/[JOB_NAME]/buildWithParameters \
--form [SOME_PARAMETER]=[ITS_VALUE] \
--form [SOME_PARAMETER]=[ITS_VALUE] \
--form [FILE_PARAMETER]=@[FULL_PATH_TO_FILE]
```

How can I add the extended choice parameter's values to this request?

Tried million different things and none of them worked :(

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add the extended choice parameter's values to this request?

Simply repeat parameter name multiple times with different values:

```
curl -X POST '[JENKINS_URL]/job/[JOB_NAME]/buildWithParameters?extChoiceName=value1&extChoiceName=value2
```

Comment: Tried but didn't work.. The extended choice field simply remains empty. Any idea why?

Comment: Hi @TempTemporary274, please add concrete full snippet (with other string and file input parameters) that didn't work; version of Jenkins and version of Extended Choice plugin.